# Parse comment before node in xml using Python

Tags: excel, xml, python-3.x, parsing, comments

Here is the format of an example of the xml node that I'm parsing data from:

```
<!-- /StationName/BACnetTemp/MNB_1_HX/HiPressureAlarm -->
<node name="HiPressureAlarm" class="tridium.control.BinaryInputNode" module="coreRuntime" release="2.301.535.v1">
  <properties>
    <position><x>576</x><y>866</y></position>
    <timeDelay>
      <duration>60</duration>
    </timeDelay>
    <eventEnable>
      <toOffnormal>true</toOffnormal>
      <toFault>false</toFault>
      <toNormal>true</toNormal>
    </eventEnable>
    <alarmText>MCD Basement Re-Heat High Pressure Alarm</alarmText>
    <changeOfStateTime>2018-05-07T08:55:04.09-4</changeOfStateTime>
    <changeOfStateCount>848</changeOfStateCount>
    <elapsedActiveTime>
      <duration>126872</duration>
    </elapsedActiveTime>
    <activeInactiveText>
      <active>Alarm</active>
      <inactive>Normal</inactive>
    </activeInactiveText>
    <alarmValueEnabled>true</alarmValueEnabled>
  </properties>
</node>  <!-- HiPressureAlarm -->
```

The comment at the beginning is the path of the point that I'm trying to export some of the data from into an excel file. I've got everything else working except being able to associate the path with the node that I'm pulling data from.

I'm able to put all comments in a list using the following code:

```
comments=soup.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))
```

I then tried the following to find the comment and associate it with the path:

```
for comment in comments:
                x='/'+nodeName
                if x in comment:
                    nodePath = comment
```

The problem is that there are several nodes with the same name with different paths, so it was giving me the same path for each node. So I added the following code immediately after the for loop:

```
if nodePath in comments:
                comments.remove(nodePath)
```

This should have worked, but the next problem is that there are several instances of the same comment in the xml and the order doesn't match the order that it is finding the node and its data, so the paths don't match with the proper node.

Is there any way of finding the node and then assigning the comment before it to a variable to then parse to the excel?

Here is my full code that parses the data:

```
def alarms(self,soup):
        alarms=soup.find_all('toOffnormal')
        comments=soup.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))
        nodeStartList=[]
        for alarm in alarms:
            nodeStart=alarm.parent.parent.parent
            nodeStartList.append(nodeStart)
        dataList=[]
        for item in nodeStartList:
            nodeName=item['name']
            for comment in comments:
                x='/'+nodeName
                if x in comment:
                    nodePath = comment
            if nodePath in comments:
                comments.remove(nodePath)
            if item.find('timeDelay')!= None:
                timeDelay=item.find('timeDelay').get_text("|", strip=True)
            else:
                timeDelay='0'

            if item.find('eventEnable')!=None:
                toOffnormal=item.find('toOffnormal').get_text("| ", strip=True)
                toFault=item.find('toFault').get_text("| ", strip=True)
                toNormal=item.find('toNormal').get_text("| ", strip=True)
            else:
                toOffnormal='false'
                toFault='false'
                toNormal='false'

            alarmText=item.find('alarmText').get_text("| ", strip=True)


            if item.find('highLimit')!= None:
                highLimit=item.find('highLimit').get_text("| ", strip=True)
            else:
                highLimit='N/A'

            if item.find('lowLimit')!= None:
                lowLimit=item.find('lowLimit').get_text("| ", strip=True)
            else:
                lowLimit='N/A'

            if item.find('deadband'):
                deadband=item.find('deadband').get_text("| ", strip=True)
            else:
                deadband='N/A'

            if item.find('lowLimitEnabled'):
                lowLimitEnabled=item.find('lowLimitEnabled').get_text("| ", strip=True)
            else:
                lowLimitEnabled='false'

            if item.find('highLimitEnabled'):
                highLimitEnabled=item.find('highLimitEnabled').get_text("| ", strip=True)
            else:
                highLimitEnabled='false'

            itemList=[nodeName,nodePath,timeDelay,toOffnormal,toFault,toNormal,alarmText,highLimit,lowLimit,deadband,lowLimitEnabled,highLimitEnabled]
            dataList.append(itemList)

        self.df=pandas.DataFrame(dataList)
        self.df.columns=['pointName','pointPath','timeDelay','toOffnormal','toFault','toNormal','alarmText','highLimit','lowLimit','deadband','lowLimitEnabled','highLimitEnabled']
        return self.df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish my goal by inserting nodePath=item.previous_element.previous_element after line 10. My result was as follows:

```
def alarms(self,soup):
        alarms=soup.find_all('toOffnormal')
        #comments=soup.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))
        nodeStartList=[]
        for alarm in alarms:
            nodeStart=alarm.parent.parent.parent
            nodeStartList.append(nodeStart)
        dataList=[]
        for item in nodeStartList:
            nodeName=item['name']
            nodePath=item.previous_element.previous_element
            #for comment in comments:
                #x='/'+nodeName
                #if x in comment:
                    #nodePath = comment
            #if nodePath in comments:
                #comments.remove(nodePath)
            if item.find('timeDelay')!= None:
                timeDelay=item.find('timeDelay').get_text("|", strip=True)
            else:
                timeDelay='0'

            if item.find('eventEnable')!=None:
                toOffnormal=item.find('toOffnormal').get_text("| ", strip=True)
                toFault=item.find('toFault').get_text("| ", strip=True)
                toNormal=item.find('toNormal').get_text("| ", strip=True)
            else:
                toOffnormal='false'
                toFault='false'
                toNormal='false'

            alarmText=item.find('alarmText').get_text("| ", strip=True)


            if item.find('highLimit')!= None:
                highLimit=item.find('highLimit').get_text("| ", strip=True)
            else:
                highLimit='N/A'

            if item.find('lowLimit')!= None:
                lowLimit=item.find('lowLimit').get_text("| ", strip=True)
            else:
                lowLimit='N/A'

            if item.find('deadband'):
                deadband=item.find('deadband').get_text("| ", strip=True)
            else:
                deadband='N/A'

            if item.find('lowLimitEnabled'):
                lowLimitEnabled=item.find('lowLimitEnabled').get_text("| ", strip=True)
            else:
                lowLimitEnabled='false'

            if item.find('highLimitEnabled'):
                highLimitEnabled=item.find('highLimitEnabled').get_text("| ", strip=True)
            else:
                highLimitEnabled='false'

            itemList=[nodeName,nodePath,timeDelay,toOffnormal,toFault,toNormal,alarmText,highLimit,lowLimit,deadband,lowLimitEnabled,highLimitEnabled]
            dataList.append(itemList)

        self.df=pandas.DataFrame(dataList)
        self.df.columns=['pointName','pointPath','timeDelay','toOffnormal','toFault','toNormal','alarmText','highLimit','lowLimit','deadband','lowLimitEnabled','highLimitEnabled']
        return self.df
```